# Solteam switch with 5 pins

Tags: motor, switches, button

I am very new to electronics, learning by my own.

I extracted a lot of switches, buttons and other components from old computer parts,
and now I am wondering can I use this as direction switch for simple motor?

I have no clue why this component has 5 contacts and where did I get it :)
But it seems to me like some sort of switch that I can lean left or right:
[image]

Where should I connect + and - for my simple computer fan project?
Thanks!

Comment: These look similar: http://www.solteam.com.tw/solteam/pdf/0/SS01.pdf

Comment: Use a multimeter in continuity test mode and figure out which contacts are closed in each of the switch positions.

Comment: There's a good chance that the pins on the ends are just there for mechanical support and have no electrical function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably can't use this to directly control the motor as it may just operate like two STSP PTM switches, or possibly a potentiometer, I can't tell just by looking at it.

Have a probe around with a multimeter to derive the pinout, I'm guessing the centre pin is the common, then see if a connection is made to any of the other pins when it is moved to either side.

Then use this to control the motor with something like a H bridge.

Comment: @Csongor Please don't edit someone else's question or answer. If you have a question, please post a new question (after taking the [tour](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/tour) which explains how this Q&A site works)

Answer (score 0):

Folks here will likely have just as little information as to how your pictured switches work as you do.

Get yourself a DVM and use the Ohms scale to measure continuity between switch pins as you move the toggle. You will soon be able to decypher the switch functionality.

If you cannot get a DVM make up a test probe with an LED, resistor, a battery and a couple of alligator clips.